# Create Multiple Choice Question with data from Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I am creating a database for my study program's inventory which can be accessed for anyone who want to request using the item.
For weeks, I am stuck with making the multiple choice question from the data in my Google Sheet Database.

These codes are the closest that I can do...Instead of creating all the choices, the program only puts different statements inside 1 choice... Could anyone help me making the proper multiple choice please?

```js
function myFunction() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1lSB55vGZeuaJC0OS3zjpuRHEDCXpUTDYC7MPUVr0tMU');  
var form = FormApp.openById('1sH-qxqiiyh3Qqq28KuYoaNftnY3RUe4FhGq6qck2eMg');

var ss_mediaandchemical = ss.getSheetByName('Stock - Media & Chemical').getRange('K2:K').getValues();
var form_mediaandchemical_question = form.getItemById('447046025').asMultipleChoiceItem();


for (var i in ss_mediaandchemical){
 form_mediaandchemical_question.createChoice(ss_mediaandchemical[i]).isCorrectAnswer;
  form_mediaandchemical_question.setChoiceValues(ss_mediaandchemical[i]);

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issues:

[setChoiceValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/multiple-choice-item#setchoicevaluesvalues) sets all the provided values in the array as choices of the item, **removing the choices that were previously set**.

Since you are iterating through the different choices, you are replacing each choice you set with the next value in the source array.

Also, `getValues()` returns a 2D array, and you want to provide a simple array. You can use [flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to fix that. Also, the source data contains several empty cells, I'd suggest removing them from the array (for example, using `.filter(String)`.

Finally, [createChoice](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/multiple-choice-item#createchoicevalue) doesn't add the choice to the item, and it should be used in combination with [setChoices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/multiple-choice-item#setchoiceschoices). It doesn't make sense to use it if you're then using `setChoiceValues`.

#### Solution:

Retrieve a simple array with values, removing empty values, and set the choices directly using `setChoiceValues`, without iterating through the array:

```
var ss_mediaandchemical = ss.getSheetByName('Stock - Media & Chemical').getRange('K2:K').getValues().flat().filter(String);
var form_mediaandchemical_question = form.getItemById('447046025').asMultipleChoiceItem();
form_mediaandchemical_question.setChoiceValues(ss_mediaandchemical);
```

If you want to create the choices via `createChoice` (it could allow more customization, like setting a choice [as correct](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/multiple-choice-item#createchoicevalue,-iscorrect) or adding a [navigation item](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/multiple-choice-item#createchoicevalue,-navigationitem)), you can do this instead:

```
var ss_mediaandchemical = ss.getSheetByName('Stock - Media & Chemical').getRange('K2:K').getValues().flat().filter(String);
var form_mediaandchemical_question = form.getItemById('447046025').asMultipleChoiceItem();
var choices = ss_mediaandchemical.map(value => form_mediaandchemical_question.createChoice(value));
form_mediaandchemical_question.setChoices(choices);
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir
I am really grateful for this